# How to make only top row larger in height than other rows in CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Using css grid for this vertical table, I want the top row height to be larger than the other rows. How can I make it, for example, 100px? I believe `grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25px);` controls the height... but I have not figured out a way to apply that to just a single top row.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Benton Sans", "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #373fff;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min-content, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25px);
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid > span {
    padding: 8px 4px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.top {
 grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    
    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>  
  <body>
<div class="grid">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="top">name</span>
        <span class="top">city</span>
        <span class="top">dob</span>
    

        <span>Person 1</span>
        <span>Aaron Kris</span>
        <span>Philippines</span>
        <span>1991-05-23T14:19:51</span>
     
        <span>Person 2</span>
        <span>Simeon McLaughlin</span>
        <span>Singapore</span>
        <span>2012-03-07T00:08:36</span>
        
        <span>Person 3</span>
        <span>Kelsie Shanahan</span>
        <span>Brazil</span>
        <span>1985-03-10T20:13:04</span>
      
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `grid-template-rows: 100px repeat(3, 25px)`.

`repeat(4, 25px)` is syntactical-sugar for `25px 25px 25px 25px`, so you can replace the first `25px` for `100px` as per your example.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Benton Sans", "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #373fff;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min-content, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 100px repeat(3, 25px);
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid > span {
    padding: 8px 4px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.top {
 grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    
    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>  
  <body>
<div class="grid">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="top">name</span>
        <span class="top">city</span>
        <span class="top">dob</span>
    

        <span>Person 1</span>
        <span>Aaron Kris</span>
        <span>Philippines</span>
        <span>1991-05-23T14:19:51</span>
     
        <span>Person 2</span>
        <span>Simeon McLaughlin</span>
        <span>Singapore</span>
        <span>2012-03-07T00:08:36</span>
        
        <span>Person 3</span>
        <span>Kelsie Shanahan</span>
        <span>Brazil</span>
        <span>1985-03-10T20:13:04</span>
      
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `grid-template-rows: 100px repeat(3, 25px);` property to the grid class and remove the .top class from both css & html

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Benton Sans", "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #373fff;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min-content, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 100px repeat(3, 25px);  /* change here */
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid > span {
    padding: 8px 4px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML

Change this:

```
<div class="grid">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="top">name</span>
        <span class="top">city</span>
        <span class="top">dob</span>
```

To this:

```
<div class="grid">
        <span>name</span>
        <span>city</span>
        <span>dob</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is specify the size you want to give to first row and after that add `repeat()` function for remaining rows.

For example,

```
grid-template-rows: 50px repeat(3, 25px);
```

This code will set the height of first row as 50px and after that it will give the remaining 3 lines 25px of height each. Like this, you can add specific height if you want to each of the row that you want to customise.

Another example,

```
grid-template-rows: 50px repeat(2, 25px) 100px;
```

This code will set the height of first row to 50px, then after that next two rows will be set 25px each and last row will be set to 100px of height.
Be careful though when using this. Use this way only if you are absolutely sure of the number of lines in your grid template, otherwise it may create some weird structure or break the ui.